# err:conflicting types for ‘addnode’;have ‘struct astnode *(struct astnode *,struct astnode *,char *)’ and warn:implicit declaration of function‘yylex’

Tags: yacc, lex

I have executed a lex and a yacc code for constructing an abstract syntax tree, but I have the following errors:

```
y.tab.c: In function ‘yyparse’:
y.tab.c:1050:16: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘yylex’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 1050 |       yychar = yylex ();
      |                ^~~~~
7th.y:24:30: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘addnode’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   24 | start:s '=' e  {$$=addnode($1,$3,"=");root=$$;}
      |                              ^~~~~~~
7th.y:24:29: warning: assignment to ‘struct astnode *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   24 | start:s '=' e  {$$=addnode($1,$3,"=");root=$$;}
      |                             ^
7th.y:28:67: warning: assignment to ‘struct astnode *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   28 |         |e '+' e                {$$=addnode($1,$3,"+");}
      |                                                                   ^
7th.y:29:67: warning: assignment to ‘struct astnode *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   29 |         |e '*' e                {$$=addnode($1,$3,"*");}
      |                                                                   ^
7th.y:30:67: warning: assignment to ‘struct astnode *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   30 |         |e '-' e                {$$=addnode($1,$3,"-");}
      |                                                                   ^
7th.y:31:67: warning: assignment to ‘struct astnode *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   31 |         |e '/' e                {$$=addnode($1,$3,"/");}
      |                                                                   ^
7th.y:34:56: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘makenode’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   34 | s:id                    {$$=makenode($1);}
      |                                                        ^       
7th.y:34:55: warning: assignment to ‘struct astnode *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   34 | s:id                    {$$=makenode($1);}
      |                                                       ^
7th.y:35:70: warning: assignment to ‘struct astnode *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   35 |         |num                    {$$=makenode($1);}
      |                                                                      ^
y.tab.c:1245:7: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘yyerror’; did you mean ‘yyerrok’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 1245 |       yyerror (YY_("syntax error"));
      |       ^~~~~~~
      |       yyerrok
7th.y: At top level:
7th.y:44:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
   44 | main()
      | ^~~~
7th.y:53:17: error: conflicting types for ‘addnode’; have ‘struct astnode *(struct astnode *, struct astnode *, char *)’
   53 | struct astnode *addnode(struct astnode *l,struct astnode *r,char *sym)
      |                 ^~~~~~~
7th.y:24:30: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘addnode’ with type ‘int()’
   24 | start:s '=' e  {$$=addnode($1,$3,"=");root=$$;}
      |                              ^~~~~~~
7th.y:63:17: error: conflicting types for ‘makenode’; have ‘struct astnode *(char *)’
   63 | struct astnode *makenode(char *data)
      |                 ^~~~~~~~
7th.y:34:56: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘makenode’ with type ‘int()’
   34 | s:id                    {$$=makenode($1);}
      |
```

**My code:**

## ast.l

```
%option noyywrap
%{
#include "y.tab.h"
extern YYSTYPE  yylval;
%}
%%
[_a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]* {yylval.name=strdup(yytext);return id;}
[0-9]+ {yylval.name=strdup(yytext);return num;}
[\n] {return 0;}
. {return yytext[0];} 
%%
```

## ast.y

```
%{
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<string.h>
    int flag=1,i=0;
    struct astnode
    {
        char *data;
        struct astnode *left,*right;
    }*root;
%}



%union{ struct astnode *node;
    char *name;
}
%token <name>  num id
%type <node> e start s
%left '+''-'
%left '*''/'
%right '='
%%
start:s '=' e  {$$=addnode($1,$3,"=");root=$$;}
    | e         {$$=$1;root=$$;}
    ;
e:s         {$$=$1;}
    |e '+' e        {$$=addnode($1,$3,"+");}
    |e '*' e        {$$=addnode($1,$3,"*");}
    |e '-' e        {$$=addnode($1,$3,"-");}
    |e '/' e        {$$=addnode($1,$3,"/");}
    |'('e')'        {$$=$2;};
    ;
s:id            {$$=makenode($1);}
    |num            {$$=makenode($1);}
    ;
%%
int yyerror()
{
    int flag=0;
    printf("invalid expr!!");
    return 0;
}
main()
{
    void printasttree(struct astnode *);
    printf("enter expr:");
    yyparse();
    printf("\nPreorder traversal of the AST tree for the given expression is:");
    printasttree(root);
    printf("\n");
}
struct astnode *addnode(struct astnode *l,struct astnode *r,char *sym)
{
    struct astnode *temp;
        temp = (struct astnode *)malloc(sizeof(struct astnode));
        temp->data=strdup(sym);
        temp->left=l;
    temp->right=r;
    return temp;
}

struct astnode *makenode(char *data)
{
    struct astnode *temp;
    temp = (struct astnode *)malloc(sizeof(struct astnode));
    temp->data=strdup(data);
    temp->left=NULL;
    temp->right=NULL;
    return temp;
}
void printasttree(struct astnode *s)
{
    if(s!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%s",s->data);
    }
    if(s->left!=NULL)
        printasttree(s->left);
    if(s->right!=NULL)
        printasttree(s->right);
}
```

I am expecting sample input and output like:

input: 12+10
output: + 12 10
input: 12*10
output: * 12 10

I used these commands for comiling and running these programs in ubuntu

```
lex ast.l
yacc -d ast.y
cc y.tab.c lex.yy.c -ll
```

upon the last command for compilation, I am getting errors. Kindly help.